# Pin-board effect with CSS

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvKwy/4/)

I want div `4` to be higher so it's closer to div `1`, but with the margins intact, sort of like the [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) pin-board style layout, does anyone know how to do that?

**HTML:**

```
<div>1<br/>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#CCC;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px 20px;
}

body { width:500px; }
```

Div `4` doesn't fit in snuggly like the rest. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvKwy/4/) for details.

What I want is something like [this link](http://masonry.desandro.com/) provided by [j08691 in an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472917/1846192).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the Pinterest layout in [most current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) using [CSS multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts), it will break in IE9 and older versions.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvKwy/8/)</kbd>. I have added some more div's for demonstration purposes.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 420px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The width of the body is set to `420px`, that value is currently derived from twice the width of a div + the width of the column gap, you could play with this value and the column gap value to add more or less space between the columns of div's.

If you need to support older browsers, you could have a look at the [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Comment: How can there be 11 negative votes and a correct answer with 2 upvotes?SO makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to accomplish this but it can't be done with CSS floats alone. A library like [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) will do it well. The reason? [The specs on floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position). In particular #5 which says, "The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.".

Comment: I agree, I think you should read more about to make a REST design (I think there is where you wanna go)

Answer (score 0):

You can float every second div to the right:

```
div:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything  http://jsfiddle.net/SvKwy/2/  Makes it worse.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in general?