# How to let DIVs floating left when no vertical space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i'm working on a horizontal page layout that currently looks like this:

Div B,C and D have the floating: left property so all DIV are aligned side by side and that is kind of what i want.

(Remember, there are much more DIVs that appear on the right while scrolling the page)

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Div A                                  |
|                                        |
|  +----------+ +----------+ +--------+  |
|  | Div B    | | Div C    | | Div D  |  |
|  |          | |          | |        |  |
|  +----------+ +----------+ |        |  |
|                            |        |  |
|                            |        |  |
|                            +--------+  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

There is one problem left, i want it so that the DIVs align vertically if there is enough space so it looks like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| Div A                     |
|                           |
|  +----------+ +--------+  |
|  | Div B    | | Div D  |  |
|  |          | |        |  |
|  +----------+ |        |  |
|               |        |  |
|  +----------+ |        |  |
|  | Div C    | |        |  |
|  |          | |        |  |
|  +----------+ |        |  |
|               +--------+  |
+---------------------------+
```

So i guess i'm looking for a way to only apply the floating: left to the DIVs if there is no vertical space left, if thats possible.

Thanks

Comment: What  about a fiddle?

Comment: Have [a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16473862/1846192) for an approach which utilizes CSS3 multiple column layout to achieve a pin board layout without using a third party library or flexbox.

Comment: I will have a look, thanks Mathijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have many easy ways to do what you want when this is just about the 3 divs you take as an example.

For instance, you could take a div E where you put your divs B & C.

Or you could go for the flexbox (flexbox FTW!)

Or you could make all the positions absolute and set everything pixel by pixel. Which would be amazignly complex if you have many divs and if you want to make it responsive... Unless there's a wonderfull library doing it for you... Which happen to be the case !

At first you had masonery : http://masonry.desandro.com/

Then you had isotope : http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

And now you have packery : http://packery.metafizzy.co/

--

All written by the same guy. The first is free, the other have a licencing price (but all the code is on github if you want to fork and make your own)

Comment: Thanks but like i said there are much more divs. Each div is a tumblr post, so it can also happen that DIV D is on the left side. I will have a look at your links.

Comment: Yes, I understood that ; this is the reason why the only good solution is to use a library like masonry :)

Comment: Yeah i did some reading and it looks like thats the way to go, thanks for the tips. Anyway, i guess it will be hard to integrate that in a tumblr theme.